# mysql - how to use INSERT...SELECT syntax for large query

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a very big data base and I need to find a trustworthy way to insert rows of a table into another, without crashing or low space errors.

Here are my tables:

```
tld: 738 rows
============================
| id (int) | tld (varchar) |
============================

sld: 116,000,000 rows
============================
| id (int) | sld (varchar) |
============================

dns: 3,000,000 rows
============================
| id (int) | dns (varchar) |
============================

cache: 300,000,000 rows  --temp data
===============================================================
| sld (varchar) | tld (varchar) | dns (varchar) | date (date) |
===============================================================

history: 128,000,000 rows
===================================================
| sld (int) | tld (int) | dns (int) | date (date) |
===================================================
```

As you can see there is a cache table for temp data.

I am inserting the cache columns `(sld, tld, dns)` in three tables `(sld, tld, dns)`
and get their ids for later use with below sql:

```
INSERT INTO `sld` (`sld`)
SELECT DISTINCT `sld` FROM `cache`
WHERE `sld` NOT IN (SELECT `sld` FROM `sld`);
```

After that I want to insert all of cache data into the history table with associated ids.
I ran this query:

```
INSERT INTO `history` (`sld`, `tld`, `dns`, `date`)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
   SELECT `sld`.`id` AS `sld`, `tld`.`id` AS `tld`, `dns`.`id` AS `dns`, `cache`.`date` AS `date` FROM `cache`, `sld`, `tld`, `dns`
   WHERE `cache`.`tld` = `tld`.`tld` AND `cache`.`sld` = `sld`.`sld` AND `cache`.`dns` = `dns`.`dns`
) AS `t`;
```

But now I get a low space error.
Then I chunk my select query with repeat syntax:

```
REPEAT

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp_cache`;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_cache`
SELECT `sld`.`id` AS `sld`, `tld`.`id` AS `tld`, `dns`.`id` AS `dns`, `cache`.`date` AS `date` FROM `cache`, `sld`, `tld`, `dns`
WHERE `cache`.`tld` = `tld`.`tld` AND `cache`.`sld` = `sld`.`sld` AND `cache`.`dns` = `dns`.`dns`
LIMIT 1000000;

INSERT INTO `history` (`sld`, `tld`, `dns`, `date`) SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `tmp_cache`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `history`.`date` = `history`.`date`;

UNTIL (SELECT count(*) FROM `tmp_cache`) = 0
END REPEAT;
```

With this method I have some other issues like:
concurrency or changing orders can affect my data...

**How can I, without getting low space errors, put the cache table into the history table with associated ids?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an `order by` on the primary key in your chunk to prevent concurrency issues

Comment: Change `NOT IN ( SELECT ... )` to `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE .. IS NULL`.

Comment: Don't use `FROM a,b WHERE ...`; use `FROM a JOIN b ON ...`